# lightSlider show all button next to thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I need create lightSlider (http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/) gallery where there is "Show all photos" next to thumbnails/.IsPager (if thumbnails count is >= 5 show button).

I tried to do it by position: absolute but show all button is over last thumbnail.

```js
$('#lightSlider').lightSlider({
  gallery: true,
  item: 1,
  loop: true,
  slideMargin: 0,
  thumbItem: 6
});
```

```css
.demo {
  width: 420px;
  position: relative;
}
ul {
  list-style: none outside none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.show-all {
  width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px #ddd;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightslider/1.1.3/css/lightslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightslider/1.1.3/js/lightslider.min.js"></script>

<div class="demo">
  <ul id="lightSlider">
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-1.jpg">
      <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-2.jpg">
      <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-3.jpg">
      <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-3.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-4.jpg">
      <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-4.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-5.jpg">
      <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-5.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-6.jpg">
      <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-6.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-7.jpg">
      <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-7.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-8.jpg">
      <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-8.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-9.jpg">
      <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-9.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-10.jpg">
      <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-10.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-11.jpg">
      <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-12.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-13.jpg">
      <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-13.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- show all is not part of thumnail list, but next to it -->
  <div class="show-all">
    <i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span>Show all photos</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Pager needs to be align in middle.

Comment: Bit confused with what you are trying to achieve. It looks awesome already..  Do you want the `show-all` to be in the middle, below the pager or to the extreme right next to the pager ?

Comment: @Searching i66.tinypic.com/9bd35f.png `show-all` next to pager, but not over container.  I have problem centering 7+ thumbnails and show-all next to it.

Comment: nice.. So just look at the library and trying few things in jsfiddle, can you check this out and tell me how far this is away from your requirement http://jsfiddle.net/pe9qnp3y/4/ . The sample you showed, is that exactly the way it should look ? And what should happen after they click show all ?

Comment: Change `thumbItem: 8` and click on last image you can see, this scrolling effect should work like in original lightSlider. Show all opens lightGallery (this part is easy). I create better new jfiddle file, I tag you when its ready.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this is going to be a little tricky but it almost works.

https://jsfiddle.net/590f2t74/1/

Don't forget that the "See all photos" is going with append method now

```
$(".lSSlideOuter").append('<div class="show-all"><i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Show all photos</span></div>');
```

P.S: For the last image issue, you can put "See all photos" image and link that to all images as the JsFiddle.

Hope this will help.

Comment: It's not what I looked but thank you! I'm no longer involved with last project where I need this. Show all text should be clickable and last picture show all is not needed. BUT +1